# How to set constant margin after last item in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

I want there to be some space after the `last item` in `RecyclerView` like the image.

The image is not in a state where the number of items is small, but in a state that is large enough to be scrollable.

In other words, when scrolling to the bottom, I want the last item to be positioned above the black bar of the image.

But what I have implemented is:

[image]

What I have implemented, as you can see in the image, is that the item penetrates the bar and is superimposed on the bottom.

When scrolling, it doesn't matter if the bar overlaps the item, but when scrolling to the bottom, I want the last item to be on top of the bar.

**ADDITION:**

**These recycler views dynamically add and delete items.**

*For once you just post the XML code.*

*If you need other code, please tell me.*

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@color/transparentBg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/add_exercise"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/add_icon"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:tint="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/add_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="ADD ROUTINE"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/add_icon" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: You explained well on the sample image, but still the provided layout lacks to apply the same explanation on it

Comment: @Zain I'm sorry, but I don't know what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your items to be displayed beneath the add Icon (which I personally do not like) and add some extra space in the bottom you can

1. Add an empty view to the end of your adapter

---

2. set `clipToPadding=false` and add a bottom padding which make the recycler view to skip that amount of height from bottom, but still show them (not clipping them) like this (I'm not sure if 160dp is a good number sum up your dimensions)

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="160dp"/>
```

---

3. And if you want your recycler to be shown above the add button (which I think looks better) you can change it like this

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button" />
```

Comment: thanks. I chose method 2 and it works the way I want it to. But did you recommend method 3?

I've already tried this method before asking the question, but as you can see from the `OP`, the `button background` is a slightly `transparent color` where the `RecyclerView's items` are visible.

But when I set the `height to 0dp` and set the `constraint`, strangely, when the button passes the item, the item is not visible.. I mean the button background becomes opaque..

Comment: When you use method 3, your recycler view stands above the button, so nothing is seen beneath it so it looks that it's opaque, actually method 1 and 2 result i  what you seem to look for, method 3 is a bit different (as you said) I personally prefer not to see items beneath my button, that's actually a UI design choice so probably method 2 was what you were looking for

Comment: Thanks so much for the great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can set your FrameLayout to a specific height and then give your recyclerview margin bottom same as frame layout height.

Or you can just change your ConstraintLayout into a LinearLayout.